# Why a path needs two slashes ( \\ ) in Eclipse?

Tags: java, string, eclipse, path, escaping

When I use the following path in Eclipse:

```
"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\selenium\geckodriver.exe"
```

There is a red `x` appears with a message that there is a mistake. But when I change it into:

```
"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe"
```

Everything is fine. Can someone explain, why is that? Do I always have to add additional slashes in a path?

Comment: your examples are identical.

Comment: no, i used two slashes, but stackoverflow automatically only shows up one slash

Answer (score 4):

In most programming languages '\' is used as an escape-character.

Examples:

`"c:\\Users"` will be `"c:\Users"`
`"My name is \"Suppe\""` will be `"My name is "Suppe""`
`"Hello\tWorld"` will be `"Hello    World"`

For more information on this topic you should read:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Even stackexchange uses backslashes as escape characters. You probably noticed that as the first version of your post had 2 identical examples.

Answer (score 2):

Because `\` character has a special meaning in Java. It's an escape character. For example if you write `\t` inside a string literal, it means a tabulator, and `\n` means a newline.

To have a literal `\` character, you have to escape it with the escape character: `\\`.

See [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) section in the Java documentation. The above is true for a lot of other languages too.

Answer (score 1):

Even in Eclipse and Netbeans, when you're typing some string, they check if this string corresponds to a [regex pattern](https://regexone.com). A single slash `\` indicates then the next character will be a regex match or a literal letter, number or whatever you want. The purpose to use double slashes `\\`, is to indicate then you want a single literal slash.

So, when they copile your typed string:

`C:\\path\\to\\exe`

will became

`C:\path\to\exe`